# Removing a group of event listeners

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of event listeners as illustrated below :

```
<a id="target0" >target0</a>

<div id="container">
   <a id="target1" >target1</a>
   <a id="target2" >target1</a>
   <a id="target3" >target1</a>
   .. more targets with event listeners
<script>
   document.getElementById("#target1").addEventListener("click", ...);
   document.getElementById("#target2").addEventListener("mouseover", ...);
   document.getElementById("#target3").addEventListener("mouseout", ...);
   ... 
</script>

</div>

<script>
   document.getElementById("#target0").addEventListener("click", ...); 
</script>
```

How do I write a function that will kill ALL DOM elements with event listeners binded to them ( with function reference or anonymous functions ) that are inside the container div ?

```
function killEvtListenersInsideContainerDiv(){
// loop to all DOM elements inside container that has event listeners and disable them
}
```

The container div is dynamically loaded by AJAX so the event listeners inside them will vary. The only one "static" is target0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will have more than ont container you should add inside class for each `a`, something like this:

```
<div>
    <a class="container1" id="#target1"></a>
    ...
</div>
```

To remove events there are two ways, I recommend the second because it easier and more modern:
1)Use native javascript, only if you can't use jquery for some technical reasons

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("container1");
elements.forEach(function(elem, i, arr) {
    element.removeEventListener("click");
}, this);
```

2)Use jquery:

```
  //set
   $('.container1').click(function() {
        alert("click");
   });
   //remove
   $('.container1').click(function(){}); //just empty function() :) the same as .click(null)
```

**UPDATE:** If you can't add class use this

javascript:

```
 var elements = document.querySelector('#idDiv a'); //or '.classId a'
 elements.forEach(function(elem, i, arr) {
 element.removeEventListener("click");
}, this);
```

jquery

```
  $('#idDiv a).click(function(){});
```

There is no way to check if event has been set before, if you really need you should implement this functionality with your hands(use flags for example). If function has already existed, new function will always override previous. In 99.9% cases it is enough.

Comment: that's cool! thanks for the response. what if i'm not able to add a class "container*". The contents in the div are from other views i do have control over. how can you modify this so it loops and checks if it has an event listener and null those ?

Comment: @user6741031 Updated